# how to check more than 1 item whether they are in another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two tables `A` and `B`. Both contain fields `phone` and `project_name`. I want to see

- how many records from table A are in table B with same phone number and project_name;
- how many records from table A are in table B with same phone number and different project_name;
- how many records from table A are in table B with different phone and same project_name;
- how many records from table A are in table B with different phone and different project_name.

I have tried to write those queries. But the outcome is bad. Could you help me?

example

```
Table A:

phone       project_name
4161234567  502
4161234568  502
4161234569  501
4161234560  502


Table B:

phone       project_name
4161234567  502
4161234568  503
4160258963  501
4160123456  504
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please add some sample data, that will help people help you with your problem. Thanks!

Comment: You really need to show the queries you've written.  Without that, we can't tell what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ask silly questions... get silly answers.  This may or may not be right depending on interpretation of the questions.

```
/*records from table A are in table B with same phone number and project_name; */
SELECT count(*), A.Phone, A.Project_name
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B 
  on A.Phone = B.Phone 
 and A.project_name = B.Project_name
GROUP BY A.Phone, A.Project_name

/*same phone number and different project_name*/
SELECT count(*), A.Phone, A.Project_name
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B 
  on A.Phone = B.Phone 
 and A.project_name <> B.Project_name
GROUP BY A.Phone, A.Project_name

/*different phone and same project_name*/
SELECT count(*), A.Phone, A.Project_name
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B 
  on A.Phone <> B.Phone 
 and A.project_name = B.Project_name
GROUP BY A.Phone, A.Project_name

/*different phone and different project_name*/
SELECT count(*), A.Phone, A.Project_name
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B 
  on A.Phone <> B.Phone 
 and A.project_name <> B.Project_name
GROUP BY A.Phone, A.Project_name
```